# numpy type conversions for arrays vs. scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I frequently use numpy, and was recently caught off guard by the way conversion between data types was handled.

Suppose I have an unsigned, 8 bit integer (uint8) with a value of 252.  Let's create a new variable which increments this by 10, and print the value of the variable and its type.  It was not obvious to me what would happen here, since 252+10 > 255 (the max for uint8).  However we see that the addition has occurred "normally", resulting in 262.  The new variable is a 64 bit integer:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.uint8(252)
>>> b = a + 10
>>> print (b, type(b))
262 <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Okay. Let's try a slightly different experiment.  This time I'll place the 252 into an array, and perform the same addition.  We see below that the result is now 6 instead of 262, meaning the addition has "wrapped around" zero.  The resulting array is still of type uint8.

```
>>> c = np.array([1,2,252], dtype='uint8')
>>> d = c + 10
>>> print (d[2], np.dtype(d[2]))
6 uint8
```

My question is this: is there a good reason why numpy's behavior differs between these cases?  Perhaps the better question is: regardless of whether the reason is good or not, what is the rule that determines when such a conversion will occur?  Is it really just array vs. scalar behavior?

Comment: To add to your confusion, or not, make `10` `uint8`, and then try the add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
b = a + 10
```

`b` has type of `10`, which is Python int, equivalent to `np.int32`.  This occurs even if the result is in the range of `np.uint8`:

```
In [151]: type(a-10)
Out[151]: numpy.int32
In [152]: np.promote_types(np.uint8,int)
Out[152]: dtype('int32')
```

In other words, adding (or otherwise combining) and `int` with `uint8` produces an `int`.

```
b = a + np.uint8(10)
```

produces a runtime overflow warning (1st time), and `b` is `uint8(6)`.

Adding 10 to the array is returning another array of the same dtype

```
c + 10
```

But note:

```
In [127]: np.array(252,np.uint8)+10
Out[127]: 262                              # like the scalar case
In [128]: np.array([1,252],np.uint8)+10
Out[128]: array([11,  6], dtype=uint8)
In [134]: np.array([252],np.uint8)+10
Out[134]: array([6], dtype=uint8)
```

There a bunch of `numpy` casting rules.  I haven't paid much attention to them, but with a bit of searching could find in the numpy docs.

`np.result_type` is another way of checking these behaviors.  It's doc may be the description of what happens when combining arrays and scalars.

```
In [157]: np.result_type(np.array([252],np.uint8), np.array(10))
Out[157]: dtype('uint8')
In [158]: np.result_type(np.array(252,np.uint8), np.array(10))
Out[158]: dtype('int32')
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type